# Is it neccesary to shutdown the oracle database before uninstalling

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I have a requirement of deleting/uninstalling a installed oracle 11g database on a Linux machine and I follow the below steps to uninstall the database.

1. Kill all processes runs with user oracle.
2. Remove oracle user and dba group.
3. Removed oracle home directory.
4. Removed logs and Oracle files like dbora.

Now I uninstall the application completely and try installing it again but next time installation is successful but the oracle is not available it throws an error after some time it shows `Oracle Initialization Or Shutdown in progress after some time it gets up and oracle is available in around 3-4 minutes.

```
RA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

Have tried basic troubleshooting steps.

1.Tried printing echo $ORACLE_HOME and $ORACLE_SID , and they were correct.

2.Also checked by logging `sqlplus / as sysdba` and tried running this query but this also failed as oracle was not available.

```
SELECT INSTANCE_NAME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS FROM V$INSTANCE;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
SQL> startup
ORA-01012: not logged on
SQL> startup
ORA-01012: not logged on
SQL> shutdown immediate
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
SQL> startup
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
```

please do let me know if I am missing anything on this while uninstallation.

Comment: First, use Oracle's packaged un-installer rather than just delete files.  Second, check the alert log for clues as to why the database is taking longer than expected to start up and become available. It may be that you are just trying to start your application too quickly.

Comment: @pmdba thanks tried checking alert logs could not find any clue now I am looking to use the oracle packaged un-installer http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_uninstall_software.htm

Comment: Your ORA-01041 error indicates a problem with your environment. If could be a lot of things, including a bug. The recommended course of action is generally to contact Oracle Support, except that your version may be too old for them to work with.

Comment: Why are you choosing to install an *unsupported version* of Oracle Database?  
Even 11.2.0.4.0 has now been formally "ditched" by Our Friends in Redwood City. 
Ideally, you should build a new [virtual] machine and install a *supported* version of your DBMS on it.